# Word 365 TOC-field not working in UK/DK-version and vice versa

Tags: microsoft-word, language, table-of-contents, microsoft-word-365

In a Word 365 template I have a TOC-field:

{TOC \n \t "KeyTaskHeading,1"}

and this works perfectly when working in documents based on the template in the Word (DK) where the template is created. There is - of course - paragraphs with the KeyTaskHeading-style assigned to them in the document.
It works in other DK versions too.

When opened in a UK-version of Word 365, the TOC-field *does not work* and the error message "No table of contents entries found" is shown.

When instead creating a new TOC-field in the UK-version of Word 365, the TOC-field looks exactly the same:

{TOC \n \t "KeyTaskHeading,1"}

And it updates perfectly – but when this document is then opened in the DK-version of Word 365 the TOC-field does not work there!

Documents based on this template need to work in both versions of Word, as they will be moved back and forth between the Word versions several times.

Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Help is really appreciated!

Comment: See the following on local style names by Word MVP Lene Fredborg. https://www.thedoctools.com/word-macros-tips/word-tips/word-style-names-in-english-danish-german-french/  https://www.thedoctools.com/word-macros-tips/word-macros/create-style-name-list/

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: This was a good guess but not the answer in this case. See the comments to the answer. The **TOC field itself** has a slightly different syntax between the two languages. One uses a comma (,) and the other uses a semicolon(;) as a separator.*

### This may be because of Local names for built-in styles.

Word MVP Lene Fredborg reviews solutions for this in her article: [Word Style Names in English, Danish, German, French](https://www.thedoctools.com/word-macros-tips/word-tips/word-style-names-in-english-danish-german-french/)

She also provides a [macro to generate a current list](https://www.thedoctools.com/word-macros-tips/word-macros/create-style-name-list/). It is in a document that you can download. It provides a table like the one shown below.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for a qualified bid.

Comment: It turns out that the two TOC fields created on Danish vs. English versions of Word were NOT identical - the Danish field was {TOC \n \t "KeyTaskHeading,1"} and the English one {TOC \n \t "KeyTaskHeading;1"}. Close, right? But not totally, the seperator after the style name is , (komma) in Danish and ; (semicolon) in English. This is apparently set deep in Windows and cannot be altered without changing heaps of other functions on the PC.

Comment: So, problem not related to built-in styles. 
(I was using a custom style, KeyTaskHeading, througout the document)

Comment: So, it is the TOC field, itself that is the culprit.